# Como utilizar un substring en un StringBuilder

Tags: vb

Necesito usar la función substring como la utilizo en el siguiente ejemplo con un string :

```
Dim Campos As String

campos = "esto es un texto de ejemplo"

Campos = Campos.Substring(0, Campos.Length - 1)
```

Pero al utilizarlo con el StringBuilder de la misma forma me tira error. alguien sabe como manejar la función de otra forma con el StringBuilder

```
Dim Campos As StringBuilder

campos.AppendLine("esto es un texto de ejemplo")

Campos.Substring(0, Campos.Length - 1)
```

Comment: el StringBuilder no es un string como tal, pero si te puede entregar un string con el cual puede usar Substring, ejemplo `sb.ToString().SubString(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringBuilder no tiene una función `SubString` ya que no está destinado a reemplazar (o mejorar) los métodos de `String`. Pero sí tiene una sobrecarga al momento de inicializarlo.

```
New StringBuilder(Texto, subStringInicio, subStringLongitud, CapacidadStringBuilder)
```

Aplicado a tu ejemplo:

```vb
Dim Campos As StringBuilder, TextoEjemplo As String = "esto es un texto de ejemplo"
Campos = New StringBuilder(TextoEjemplo, 0, TextoEjemplo.Length, 255)
```

Si no te convence, mejor aplicar el `subString` antes o después de usar `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Funciono bien, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te da error porque estás invocando mal la cadena de la stringbuilder.

Tenés que cambiar:

```
Campos.Substring(0, Campos.Length - 1)
```

Por esto:

```
// Obtengo mi cadena del stringbuilder
Dim cadena = cadenas(0).ToString()    

//Creo la substring de mi cadena
cadena.Substring(0, cadena.Length - 1)
```

Saludos!